# Windows Phone issue when selecting multiple nodes with System.Linq.Xml

Tags: linq-to-xml, windows-phone-7.1

I ran into this issue last night when I was prototyping with WP7.1.

I have a class library that I am using as a repository for all my data access.  In this class library I am making a REST call and grabbing the XML.  Everything is working up to this point.  From the Stream returned I am turning it into an XElement. Then when I do something like `XElement.Elements()` or `XElement.Descendents()` I am receiving the following exception when I look at the `System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current` member. (I am not sure why it says this but that's what I see when I expand the object)

`'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

At this point I think to myself that it is a namespace issue so I write the following code and receive the same exception.

```
var f = new XElement("Foo", new XElement("Bar", 1));
var b = f.Elements("Bar");
```

[image: The error...]

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.  I really want to use linq-to-xml instead of a bunch of loops to construct my objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this was working as expected with the deferred execution.

When I call a `ToList` or something similar on the collection, I get the expected results.  I guess there must be a bug or something in this instance when I try to evaluate the expression during a breakpoint (the aforementioned exception).  I guess I was trusting the debugger too much :)

Answer (score 1):

When you perform linq operation and assign it to the "var"  variable, what really happens is the query instructions are getting stored in that. Not the actual data set is getting stored on that.
When you try to access data from that the instruction get executed and the you will get the data. 
That’s why you are not seeing any data on a breakpoint.

Comment: I understand that it is deferred execution.  When you hover over the "refresh" symbol it executes and I can usually view the objects (when working on other types of projects).  In the case of WP7 and this Linq-to-XML, for some reason I could not view the data during a breakpoint.